# gspread - get specific columns by column name

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have a sheet with the struct below.

```
COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | COLUMN3
0       | 3       | 1
1       | 3       | 
2       | 5       | 4
4       | 2       | 2
```

How can I return just the column 1 and 2 by its column name? Not by the index.
Using the *wks.get_all_values()* as shown bellow, it will return all columns of the sheet.

My code:

```
ss = gs.open(args['name'])
wks = ss.worksheet(args['worksheet'])
data = wks.get_all_values()
headers = data.pop(0)
df = pd.Dataframe(data, columns=headers)
```

I was needing something like, *wks.get_columns(['COLUMN1','COLUMN2'])*

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Are you specifically and only looking for a script solution? This could easily be done with a single `FILTER` formula. If you are interested in the formula approach, in order to allow maximum efficiency, please supply the actual sheet name and full range of columns that may be included (e.g., A:Z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the columns by the header values.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the specific columns are retrieved from the values retrieved with `wks.get_all_values()`. In this case, one API call is used. For example, when the specific columns are retrieved after the header row was retrieved, 2 API calls are retrieved. So I proposed this method.

```py
headers = ["COLUMN1", "COLUMN3"] # Please set the header values you want to retrieve.

ss = gs.open(args['name'])
wks = ss.worksheet(args['worksheet'])
values = wks.get_all_values()
data = zip(*(e for e in zip(*values) if e[0] in headers))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
```

- When this script is run using your sample sheet in your question, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    0  COLUMN1  COLUMN3
    1        0        1
    2        1
    3        2        4
    4        4        2
  ```
- When you want to retrieve `data` as a list, please modify `data = zip(*(e for e in zip(*values) if e[0] in headers))` to `data = [list(f) for f in zip(*(e for e in zip(*values) if e[0] in headers))]`.